# Kentico AD authenticatoin

Tags: kentico

We've having some issues getting this to work. Do we need to import the full user list from AD into Kentico? We have an authentication system (F5), but that portion hasn't been enabled yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark, you have to specify AD connection string and add AD user and role providers to your web.config as described [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Configuring+mixed-mode+authentication). Once this is done Kentico will create user account for anyone, who logs in using data from AD.

Comment: That's where were at and still hitting a wall. Does the LDAP connection string and user name need to be in a specific format?

Comment: See LDAP connection strings @ http://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string. Make sure account, you've configured for membership and roles providers has appropriate permissions for AD. Check event log for errors; if you can't see appropriate errors there I'd try to implement simple app that would connect to AD with credential you're using and read some data from it - if there is something wrong with account you'll get an exception with description, which will give you an idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I may be late on this, however Kentico has an excellent utility which is available where you install Kentico called "Kentico AD Import Utility".

[Using this](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Kentico+AD+Import+Utility) you can import your AD users to Kentico if that's what you were/are trying to accomplish.

Cheers,
Chetan

Comment: We're going to use this to bring in the AD roles, may have to do the same for the users. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import all the users. You do need to set one user up manually to make them the administrator.

Have you followed all these 
[steps in the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Configuring+Windows+AD+authentication)?  if so, what issues are you having?

Comment: My account is set as a global admin, but we haven't been able to get a user authenticate unless they were in Kentico. I've set up the web.config and IIS authentication.

Comment: So had Kentico support on a call yesterday, still can't get basic windows auth to work. We're in a holding pattern untill we hear back.